# Career advise - in scope?

Tags: discussion

I understand this question was migrated from main site. But still - Is it a good question for Meta site?

[.net or SP? Career help pls :)](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1411/72613)

Comment: It's a horrible question. It's essentially asking complete strangers to make major life decisions for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No! Career advice is better handled by practitioners in the Recruitment industry. Answer among SharePoint experts may be very biased...